# Why global ordinals are built on field data not doc_values?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I have a field "location" like this

```
 "location": {
        "type": "string",
        "index": "not_analyzed",
        "store": true,
        "fielddata": {
          "format": "doc_values"
        }
      },
```

However,when I use Terms Aggregation with this field I see this kind of log

```
[2015-05-13 15:42:56.210][DEBUG][index.fielddata.plain] Global-ordinals[location][361372] took 206 ms
[2015-05-13 17:55:44.692][DEBUG][index.fielddata.plain] Global-ordinals[location][461584] took 230 ms
[2015-05-13 17:56:21.907][DEBUG][index.fielddata.plain] Global-ordinals[location][263096] took 1205 ms
```

and also I can see the Java heap size has been increased which in result long old garbage collection.

Why Does doc_values field uses java heap?Because I store them as well?
Can I avoid the garbage collection?

Answer (score 6):

Global ordinals are structures which map each unique term in a field to a unique number. This needs to be generated so that memory fingerprint and computation is better.

You can learn more about global ordinals [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/preload-fielddata.html#global-ordinals).

Here is a summary of this info in case this link dies one day:

## Global Ordinals

One of the techniques used to reduce the memory usage of string fielddata is called ordinals.

Imagine that we have a billion documents, each of which has a `status` field. There are only three statuses: `status_pending`, `status_published`, `status_deleted`. If we were to hold the full string status in memory for every document, we would use 14 to 16 bytes per document, or about 15 GB.

Instead, we can identify the three unique strings, sort them, and number them: 0, 1, 2.

```
Ordinal | Term
-------------------
0       | status_deleted
1       | status_pending
2       | status_published
```

The original strings are stored only once in the ordinals list, and each document just uses the numbered ordinal to point to the value that it contains.

```
Doc     | Ordinal
-------------------------
0       | 1  # pending
1       | 1  # pending
2       | 2  # published
3       | 0  # deleted
```

This reduces memory usage from 15 GB to less than 1 GB!